# Adding too many locations on Gmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps

What i want to do is: 
I have so many Geo Locations. I want to add them all on Google Map, and these points will be transparent (not 100% transparent).
The area that has more locations, its color will be darker while locations are upon each other.

Check out this preview, i need similar to this, but on google maps:

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried any research of your own? There are plenty of examples online for using custom markers with Google Maps API:
http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/10/personalize-your-map-with-a-custom-map-marker/

Comment: Thank you @BenM i was confused because of too many examples. I am asking here to get the right thing to do it

Comment: So what have you already tried?

Comment: i didn't try, i am looking. I still can't find what exactly i need.

Comment: Google maps can help, but i have too many locations

Comment: How do you mean "too many locations"?

Comment: i mean Geo locations are over 1000

Comment: Sounds like a heatmap may be useful: http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles.html

Comment: As far as I know, Google doesn't limit the number of markers you can add to a map?

Comment: Its similar to HeatMap, but the image attached gives the exact of what i need

Comment: So, what have you tried? ...or would you like us to write it for you and serve it on a silver platter?

Comment: I am going to use Google Maps. I think i should draw all points on the map. This may take time to make the  Map ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two great techniques i have used in the past...

1. [cluster markers](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html)
2. [heat maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps)

Cluster markers allow you to condense huge amounts of markers into something that can easily be rendered.
heat maps are exactly what they sound like.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You need a Heat map..

http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/google-maps-api-gets-heat-maps.html

Answer (score 0):

This article from the documentation addresses your question:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

FYI - in the Google Maps API v3 1000 is not "too many", looks like you just need a custom icon (your partially transparent circle).

Here is an example with lots of semi-transparent circles (native Google Maps API polygons):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_exampleF.html